# How do I use Microsoft Graph OAuth code flow to produce a token that can read mail?

Tags: oauth, microsoft-graph-api

Steps to recreate require:

- A web browser
- A command console with CURL installed.
- An existing Microsoft Azure account.
- An existing Azure App registration (see https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_AAD_RegisteredApps/ApplicationsListBlade).

Step 1: Replace "MY_CLIENT_ID" with an Azure client ID for an authorized application.

https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A12345&response_mode=query&resource=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F&state=12345&prompt=admin_consent&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2Fmail.read

Step 2: Enter the URL in a web browser address bar.

Step 3: Proceed to authorize the application to read email using an existing Azure account.  (The browser URL will change to one with an OAuth code.)

Step 4: Copy the OAuth code.

Step 5: In the CURL command below:

- Replace "MY_CLIENT_ID" with an Azure client ID for an authorized application.
- Replace "MY_CLIENT_SECRET" with the client secret for the authorized application.
- Replace "MY_OAUTH_CODE" with the OAuth code.

`curl -X POST -H "content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d "grant_type=authorization_code&code=MY_OAUTH_CODE&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A12345&client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2Fmail.read&client_secret=MY_CLIENT_SECRET" "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token"`

Step 6: Enter the CURL command in a command console.  (A valid request token will be returned.)

Step 7: Replace "MY_REQUEST_TOKEN" in the CURL command below with the request token and execute the command in a command console.

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer MY_REQUEST_TOKEN" "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/"
```

Notice that the basic account info is returned - meaning the token is VALID.

Step 8: Replace "MY_REQUEST_TOKEN" in the CURL command below with the request token and execute the command in a command console.

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer MY_REQUEST_TOKEN" "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages"
```

This error is returned:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "ResourceNotFound",
    "message": "Resource could not be discovered.",
  }
}
```

Comment: Note that I can read emails if I get an auth code using the URL https://login.live.com/oauth20_authorize.srf?client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID&scope=mail.read+offline_access+openid+profile+user.read&redirect_uri=https%3a%2f%2flogin.microsoftonline.com%2fcommon%2foauth2%2fnativeclient&response_type=code&state=7edef1d2-03ef-4880-a29a-643ce18c22720bd49a42-5324-44bb-a452-057dc5226c80&code_challenge=BjnR7aD6NRt7VyHP_hqK17RRcReI8LDizI5wEKgOTk4&code_challenge_method=S256&x-client-SKU=MSAL.Desktop&x-client-Ver=4.13.0.0&uaid=78913d5e38bb4c1db4ad7de906f2668d&msproxy=1&issuer=mso&tenant=common&ui_locales=en-US

Answer (score 0):

Since you are trying to read mails, please setup permissions to your registered app with required permissions i.e., Mail.ReadBasic, Mail.Read.

Please go through the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-365-api/api/version-2.0/mail-rest-operations

View the documentation, this is the client class code: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Graph/Requests/Generated/GraphServiceClient.cs

Here is an example :

```
private static GraphServiceClient GetClient(string accessToken, IHttpProvider provider = null)
{
        var delegateAuthProvider = new DelegateAuthenticationProvider((requestMessage) =>
        {
            requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", accessToken);

            return Task.FromResult(0);
        });

        var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(delegateAuthProvider, provider ?? HttpProvider);

        return graphClient;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply.  The API Permissions for my App do include  "Mail.Read".  I am able to read mail if I get the token using the Test Application provided by Microsoft at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-windows-desktop.  And if I use exactly the same URLs and parameters that this Test Application they succeed in obtaining a token that will read emails.  So I'm currently examining the URLs and parameters used by the Test Application to determine which parameters are required to read emails.

Comment: For your reference ,In the url  **Scope** is  the parameter which helps in  permission in URL

Comment: Yes - I was setting the scope to "mail.read".  The Test Application sets the scope to "mail.read+offline_access+openid+profile+user.read".  I'm still testing to determine which parameters are required to read mail.

Comment: I am not  sure why you are testing. In URL level Scope is the only parameters which has ability to set permissions.

Answer (score 0):

This morning I was able to access the email messages of a MS Outlook account using the URIs recommended by the Microsoft OAuth code flow document here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow

It appears that one or more parameters I’d been using in my testing last week was preventing email access.  (Or a required parameter was absent.)

---

Step: Paste Code Request URI into browser navigation bar:

https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A12345&response_mode=query&scope=openid%20offline_access%20https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2Fmail.read&state=12345

### Step: Authorize in the Browser prompt.

Step: Copy "code" from browser navigation bar into this CURL command:

curl -X POST -H "content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d "client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2Fmail.read&code=MY_CODE&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A12345&grant_type=authorization_code" "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token"

---

Step: Copy the access token from the previous CURL command into this CURL command:

curl -H "Authorization: Bearer MY_TOKEN" "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages"